# Showing the polar of a set is bounded in TVS using Bipolar theorm.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X,\mathcal{U}$ is a locally convex TVS and $Y,\mathcal V$ is a TVS where the elements of $Y$ are $\mathcal{U}$ continuous linear functionals and $\mathcal{V}$ is the topology induced by the maps $f_x(y)=<y,x>$. I would like to show the polar of some open neighborhood of the origin, $U$ is totally bounded, where the polar of $U$ is;

$U^\circ=\{f \in Y|\langle f,u\rangle \leq 1 \forall u \in U\}$

where $<f,u>$ is interpreted as $f(u)$

According to; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem I should be able to use the fact that $(U^\circ)_\circ=cl_{w^*}(conv(U))$. But I can't see any connection.

Further I don't really understand the concept of totally bounded outside the context of metric spaces. My naive understanding is that I need to take some arbitrary n-hood of $\vec{0_{Y}}$ and show that I can translate it some finite number of times, take the union of the translations, and cover $U^\circ$. This seems very difficult, especially considering the mysterious nature of the topology of $Y$. I think a subbasis elt. in $Y$ looks something like;

$$\{y \in Y| |\langle y,x_0 \rangle|<r\}$$
for some $x_0 \in X$ and $r >0$

But that's really the extent of my understanding.

EDIT; An idea;

$U$ is a n-hood of the origin and is therefore absorbing, and clearly $U \subset U^\circ)_\circ$.

Take a N-hood of the origin, $V \subset \mathcal{V}$. Then $V$ contains an open set of the form;

$$R=\{y \in Y|\max_i |\langle y,x_i \rangle|<r, (x_i)_{i \leq m}\}$$

As it is a finite intersection of subbasis elts. So there is some scalar $c$ such that $(U^\circ)_\circ \supset c^{-1}(x_i)_{i\leq m}$.

Then I think $\frac{2c}{r}R$ should contain $U^\circ$ since if $f \in U^\circ$ then;

$$|\langle f,x_i \rangle|=c|\langle f,x_i/c \rangle|\leq c < 2c$$

So $f \in \frac{2c}{r}R$ So I can conclude $U^\circ$ is bounded. Now how to show that its totally bounded?

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_system I only need the fact that $X$ distinguishes points of $Y$, why is this?

Comment: Theorem 3.15 in Rudin's FA proves that the polar is weak* compact. Compactness implies total boundedness.

Comment: But I want to show that it's compact in the end!

Comment: I can already show Y is complete, so I need totally bounded.